# Bootstrap 3 two columns in container with 100% width backgrounds

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

can anybody help me to make in bootstrap 3 layout with 2 columns with background with 100% width?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way is set the background to the row width 50% width:

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>left</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>right</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
background-color: #e1e2e4;
background-image: url('image.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 50% 100%;
}
```

bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/yDCLfN2DSb

Answer (score 0):

Are you having trouble with the columns staying within the container? The columns also need to be in a row. This article may help: http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

If you want two columns beside each other this is one way to do it.

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

For a solution to this question see here: http://bootply.com/Y8SX4b3F6g

Comment: I want to have a background split in half with 100% width of body (see example img in my ask)...

Comment: Oh ok, is this for images? Bootstrap isn't great for this but you could use a <header> tag directly in the body and put your columns in it (you could also take the padding away from the columns). This is not a great solution but it works and isn't really invalid markup.

Comment: No this is not good, i need background on 100% width, but other for left side of row and other for right side of row, and this is no problem, but also I need have a container with content (default bootstrap width) centered in window - this is all the problem...

Comment: Ok. To get this working you could create a css class with a background image for each side and add the class to each column 'background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;' . Then before the columns but inside the header create a container and add your text in it. If you play about with that, you should get it to work.

Comment: no, this can't work or i don't understand, can You try this on bootply?

Comment: Just saw your updated picture. For that put a container at the top, your header in the middle and a container below it. What your trying to do is not possible with bootstrap, there's too much padding (for good reasons). So your trying to do a workaround and with using the header with the css I've provided you'll be able to do the work around. Also if you do find my answer helpful please mark my answer. If this comment doesn't help then let me know and I'll find some time later to do that.

Comment: Please see this:
http://www.bootply.com/WJUQt8S10n
i want to make background of "col-xs-6 #1" to 100% width of the left side - not only to end of container...

Comment: It's not great but I think it's the only way to do it. I have used (and have seen in multiple themes) the header being used directly in the body for a 100% width image, so it's something that is used out there so I would use it if this is what you need to do.